# Posix and intl extension on windows

Tags: php, windows, posix, intl

When I installed Symfony2 sandbox and try to check requirements by check.php I had 2 problems. My server don't have posix and intl extensions.
I'm using WampServer 2.1e (32 bits) on Windows 7 32bit so my versions of apache and php are:
Apache 2.2.17 VC6 ThreadSafe
Php 5.3.5

I was trying to apply intl extension from http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.3.5-Win32-VC6-x86.zip
but i have weird error in apache log: "Can't find extension in c:/wamp/..." I'm sure that extension is in correct directory and enabled in php.ini.

With posix extension I have bigger problem. I can't find it at all on windows platform. In documentation of php it is said that it should be enabled by default, but it isn't.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using XAMPP 1.7.4 with PHP 5.3.5 and i experience the same problems.

The problem concerning *intl* extension i solved this way: i copied files named *icu*36.dll* from php installation folder to C:\Windows

Resorurces for *intl*: http://www.tiv.net/2010/12/php-intl-extension-windows-apache.html

Talking about the *posix* issue, i haven't even searched, becase this extension is used to colorize the CLI output and Windows shell isn't able to do it.