# alternative to posix_getpwuid() and posix_getpwuid(fileowner('some_id')) combo

Tags: php, apache, posix

Anyone knows any good alternative to:

- `posix_getpwuid()`

and

- `posix_getpwuid(fileowner())` combo

reason:

php5.3/win platform safe

especially php 5.3 safe

Comment: If you want posix on windows, you need to compile it in. See as well [POSIX for Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX_for_Windows). - Related: [Posix and intl extension on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741396/posix-and-intl-extension-on-windows)

Comment: I'd rather do without it, but I'm having problems dealing with getting fileowner group usernames in php

Comment: Just use the right tools for the platform your scripts are running on, e.g. [`get_current_user`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php). But generally, windows is not posix, so it does not have the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Win concerns me only as far as XAMPP I have locally installed. However get_current_user does not seem to be an alternative to  posix_getpwuid really. It shows current user of a file. If I want owner name (not ID) of a file not being used at the moment, or a directory then get_current_user is not a good tool. At least it does not seem to be.

Comment: That's why I added "But generally, windows is not posix, so it does not have the functionality you're looking for". What I meant is, you need to find the function that does the same for windows (which highly likely does not exists as windows is not posix). I hope the message is more clear now. If you only need it for testing purposes in your local development engine, just check if the function exists, and if not, define it in PHP and return some mock value.

Comment: Lets forget windows totally. My concern is that I have NOT found ANY PHP working alternative for posix_getpwuid. That is why I posted this question, hoping that someone has such alternative.

Comment: That's most certainly by design: How can a non-POSIX system return POSIX-UIDs for files? That just does not go together. You can't interview a chinese person in czech. That won't work w/o a translator. Check for the `stats` function and see if you can make use of it but I assume that's as far as it can get and most certainly it does not provide you a workaround. You would need a translation for the meaning for a POSIX-UID onto whatever the system is providing in a comparable manner.

Comment: That is what I though. Thank you for your time "hakre".